# Photoshop opens dialog box when trying to fill a layer with transparent pixels locked

Tags: photoshop-script

This script should set the layer to lock transparent pixels, and then fill the layer with a color. It does that, except when it gets to the fill stage, it opens the fill dialog box, and you have to hit okay.

If you omit the transparent pixel line, it runs as expected, no dialog box.

Is there a way to suppress the box? Or am I doing something wrong that's causing the box to open?

```
#target photoshop
app.bringToFront();

doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.artLayers[0].isBackgroundLayer = false;
doc.artLayers[0].transparentPixelsLocked = true;
app.activeDocument.selection.fill(app.foregroundColor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to not lock the layer, and instead use an AM code to fill the layer honoring transparency.

Code:

```
#target photoshop 

app.bringToFront(); 



doc = app.activeDocument; 

doc.artLayers[0].isBackgroundLayer = false; 

doc.activeLayer = doc.artLayers[0];

// =======================================================

var idFl = charIDToTypeID( "Fl  " );

    var desc18 = new ActionDescriptor();

    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );

    var idFlCn = charIDToTypeID( "FlCn" );

    var idFrgC = charIDToTypeID( "FrgC" );

    desc18.putEnumerated( idUsng, idFlCn, idFrgC );

    var idOpct = charIDToTypeID( "Opct" );

    var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );

    desc18.putUnitDouble( idOpct, idPrc, 100.000000 );

    var idMd = charIDToTypeID( "Md  " );

    var idBlnM = charIDToTypeID( "BlnM" );

    var idNrml = charIDToTypeID( "Nrml" );

    desc18.putEnumerated( idMd, idBlnM, idNrml );

    var idPrsT = charIDToTypeID( "PrsT" );

    desc18.putBoolean( idPrsT, true );

executeAction( idFl, desc18, DialogModes.NO );
```

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1475826